# При отправки файла на почту, как изменить имя файла на свое имя, оставляя формат файла? Заранее огромное спасибо

Tags: php, email

```
for ($ct = 0; $ct < count($_FILES['files2']['tmp_name']); $ct++) {
    $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['files2']['name'][$ct]));
    $filename = $_FILES['files2']['name'][$ct];
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files2']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
            $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
        } else {
            $msg .= 'failfile';
        }
}
```

Comment: Нужно от оригинального имени файла забрать расширение и сохранить в переменной, а потом просто прилепить его к новому имени. Как расширение получить - можно загуглить, вариантов хватает, например https://habr.com/ru/post/37753/

Comment: `$filename = $_FILES['files2']['name'][$ct];` сюда своё записывайте имя файла и расширение, +- так `$filename = 'custom_name.'.end(explode('.', $_FILES['files2']['name'][$ct]));`

Comment: Благодарю за решение!